# selenium RC doesnt run the whole test suite

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to run an HTML testSuite with Selenium RC. The browser starts, the first test runs, and it stops. It doesn't continue to the second test case. I named both the test cases with .html extension. I am using Firefox.

If I run them manually, individually from the selenium RC test runner window they run ok. What am I missing, this seems pretty simple but yet I'm not able to get this working.

I am using Selenium RC 1.0.3

> `java -jar selenium-server.jar
>   -firefoxProfileTemplate"C:\Users\sicky\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zvt0jj7c.default"
>   -htmlsuite "*firefox" "https://4.17.8.9/" "C:\Users\sicky\Documents\selenium scripts\suite.html"
>   "C:\Users\sicky\Documents\selenium scripts\results.html"`

What am I missing?

Comment: ok I figured this out. What I was doing was , I was converting the existing scripts into HTML. Apparently it doesnt work that way. It looks like I have to name them with html extension when I make those test cases itself, then the whole suite will run

Answer (score 5):

ok I figured this out. What I was doing was , I was converting the existing scripts into HTML. Apparently it doesnt work that way. It looks like I have to name them with html extension when I make those test cases itself, then the whole suite will run –

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had the same behaviour and my test scripts were in fact created in Selenium IDE and had the proper .html extension.
However! The test suite itself didn't have the .html extension. I just added it and it started working properly.