# Selenium Test Results are empty

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [selenium RC doesnt run the whole test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671511/selenium-rc-doesnt-run-the-whole-test-suite)

I've Jenkins and selenium configured to run tests after the app is build, everything is ok till the moment that selenium tests should run, actually the selenium test suite starts correctly and then it stops after the first test and does not go forward.

I'm using VNC to watch what is happening.

The logs produces by selenium are empty.

Im testing those test via

```
java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server-jar -browserSessionReuse  -htmlSuite *firefox https://test-a.4pm.si /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/4pm_test/workspace/4pm_ee-test/selenium_tests/suite.html /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/4pm_test/workspace/selenium-result.html
```

the selenium-result.html is empty it just execute the first test which is OK and stops there

is there any selenium server setting I need to set?

Comment: What does your test file look like?

Comment: eh ignore this question ... I had the test files withowt the .html extension it looks like that selenium suite neads tests with .html extenstion, after I've added the extension and edited the suite to link right the suite started to work...I've found afterwords the answer here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671511/selenium-rc-doesnt-run-the-whole-test-suite) .... sory for posting the same question again